# Is there a way to hide an element from another react component?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm fairly new to react and css and I'm a bit stuck.
I have an animated NavBar that opens on a button click and fills the page - however, because of the way my app is structured I'm struggling to hide the component underneath the nav - i.e. home page, as elements with properties like position: absolute aren't being hidden underneath it.

Right now, my css classes for this are:

```
.nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1400px at 95% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1400px at 95% -10%);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .nav-links.close {
    clip-path: circle(100px at 95% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 95% -10%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
```

And I simply toggle the classes with this:

```
toggleNavbar() {
    if (this.state.navBarActive === false) {
      this.setState({
        navBackStyle: 'white',
        navClass: 'nav-links open',
        navBarActive: !this.state.navBarActive,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        navBackStyle: '#5b78c7',
        navClass: 'nav-links close',
        navBarActive: !this.state.navBarActive,
      });
    }
  }
```

My react components are all in the app.js, with a components folder containing the navbar, home etc.

My css files are also structured as components and imported with scss. I understand I could have everything in one file to make it easier to hide other elements but that won't be very easy to work with, as this is  big project.

Comment: That sounds like a `z-index` issue. Have you tried setting `z-index: 9999` for the navbar (*assuming it is positioned*) ?

Comment: You absolute legend, worked straight away. Thank you! :)